# How can I handle a common button across all pages in Page Object Model - Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, frameworks, webdriver

In a Page Object Model, how do you handle a common button which is there across multiple pages?

Ex: In a search results page, **NEXT** button.

**Condition:** I do not want to repeat the action of clicking the button on each page.  I want to write the code just once and want to reuse it across pages.How do you do that?

Comment: I think you are asking about pagination.like there will be a multiple pages with one button to see next.

Comment: Use a base class and extend this class for PO which have these buttons.

Comment: Hi Lokesh, can u pls give me the sample code / pseudo code ? i.e what to have base class and what will be in the derived class...

Comment: I think we need more information about what your application under test looks like, and how your current Page Object Model is implemented.  As Grasshopper indicates, you need to put your common button in a base class, or another page that extends this class, and extend this for your pages that share the button.  however, I wouldn't do it that way for something like a search results...for that I would have a single page with an element that contains dynamic content, the results.  So, more info about your particular case would help us help you.

Comment: Just think about which object oriented concept help you to remove code duplication ( already indicated by Grasshopper ).